# Difference between "no module named" and "cannot import name" in Python

Tags: python, flask

I am wondering about the difference between two error messages in Python. I am trying to set up my Flask framework and run a simple Hello World.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

vs.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'app'
```

I get one of these errors or the other, depending which directory I put my "app" directory inside. So in a statement like

```
from app import app
```

which term is the module, and which is the name?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the first case, the `app` module cannot be found.
- In the second case, the `app` module can be found but the `app` element (class, function, ...) inside `app` cannot be found or imported for various reasons (not found, cyclic dependencies, missing shared library, ...)